# Using FieldList and FormField

Tags: python, wtforms

We have the following forms and we are trying to create list of `GroupRoleForms` for each group.

```
class FullNameMixIn():
    full_name = TextField(
        'Full name', [
            validators.required(message=u"Full name is required")
        ])

class GroupRoleForm(Form):
    group =BooleanField('Group', default=False)
    role = SelectField(
            'Role',choices=[
            ("none", "----------"), 
            ('approver', 'Approver'),
            ('editor', 'Editor')
            ])

class AdminEditUserForm(Form, FullNameMixIn):
    group_roles = FieldList(FormField(GroupRoleForm))
```

How can we create a `AdminEditUserForm` instance that contains a pre-populated list of `GroupRoleForms`?

At the moment we are trying to do it this way:

```
form = forms.AdminEditUserForm()
for group in  company.groups:
    group_role_form = forms.GroupRoleForm()
    group_role_form.group.label =  group.name
    group_role_form.group.name = group.id
    form.group_roles.append_entry(group_role_form)
return dict(edit_user_form = form )
```

Comment: did you ever get around to solving this? if you did, please post your solution

Comment: do you want to append fields dynamically is that it? you know that append_entry doesn't get formdata.

Comment: Simple, by adding an init function, that does exactly that.

Comment: I think your dynamic form composition might be overdoing it a bit. You can achieve the desired effect by just binding your data to the top-level form object, letting **WTForms** do the work.

Comment: I've created a full working example here: https://github.com/sebkouba/dynamic-flask-form

Answer (score 8):

### Explanation

In your `data` or `formdata` keyword arguments for the `Form` you just need an dictionary with a `key` that matches the `FieldList` subfield that contains an iterable. The items in that iterable need in turn have items w/ attributes that match with `FieldList`'s list of fields.

If you follow the example below I get nested Forms that are pre-populated just fine.

### The Code

```
from collections import namedtuple

from wtforms import validators
from wtforms import Form
from wtforms import SelectField
from wtforms import BooleanField
from wtforms import TextField
from wtforms import FieldList
from wtforms import FormField

from webob.multidict import MultiDict

# OP's Code
class FullNameMixIn():
    full_name = TextField(
        'Full name', [
            validators.required(message=u"Full name is required")
        ])

class GroupRoleForm(Form):
    group =BooleanField('Group', default=False)
    role = SelectField(
            'Role',choices=[
            ("none", "----------"), 
            ('approver', 'Approver'),
            ('editor', 'Editor')
            ])

class AdminEditUserForm(Form, FullNameMixIn):
    group_roles = FieldList(FormField(GroupRoleForm))

# create some groups
Group = namedtuple('Group', ['group', 'role'])
g1 = Group('group-1', 'none')
g2 = Group('group-2', 'none')

# drop them in a dictionary 
data_in={'group_roles': [g1, g2]}

# Build form 
test_form = AdminEditUserForm(data=MultiDict(data_in))

# test print
print test_form.group_roles()
```

### The Rendered HTML(Truncated)

```
<ul id="group_roles">
   <li>
      <label for="group_roles-0">Group Roles-0</label> 
      <table id="group_roles-0">
         <tr>
            <th><label for="gr
               oup_roles-0-group">Group</label></th>
            <td><input checked id="group_roles-0-group" name="group_roles-0-group" type="checkbox" value="y"><
               /td>
         </tr>
         <tr>
            <th><label for="group_roles-0-role">Role</label></th>
            <td>
               <select id="group_roles-0-role" name="group_roles-0-role">
                  <option
                     selected value="none">----------</option>
                  <option value="approver">Approver</option>
                  <option value="editor">Editor</option>
               </select>
            </td
               >
         </tr>
      </table>
   </li>
   <li>
      <label for="group_roles-1">Group Roles-1</label> 
      <table id="group_roles-1">
         <tr>
            <th><label for="group_roles-1-gro
               up">Group</label></th>
            <td><input checked id="group_roles-1-group" name="group_roles-1-group" type="checkbox" value="y"></td>
         </tr>
         <tr>
            <t
               h>
            <label for="group_roles-1-role">Role</label></th>
            <td>
               <select id="group_roles-1-role" name="group_roles-1-role">
                  <option selected value
                     ="none">----------</option>
                  <option value="approver">Approver</option>
                  <option value="editor">Editor</option>
               </select>
            </td>
         </tr>
      </table>
      <
      /li>
</ul>

...
```

Comment: Interesting enough WTForms says that you cannot use boolean fields in FieldLists due to html limitation, didn't check your sample but be careful.

Comment: mreh still holds true for all other field types. `SubmitField` doesn't work for obvious reasons. `BooleanField` must fail when encoding the form, but its likely very subtle(takes the value of the last checkbox or something)

Comment: Recently I found this answer. Based on what works for me, I think the FieldList limitation regarding boolean & submit fields does apply directly to these fields, but not to subforms included with FormField. Also the data argument in `Form(data=...)` does not need to be a MultiDict, a standard dict will do.

Comment: @VPfB - This is true. You could just have `FieldList(FormField(MyFormWithBooleanFields))` and it works fine.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not familiar with these packages but I'll take a stab:

```
class AdminEditUserForm(Form, FullNameMixIn):
    def __init__(self, groups):
        super(AdminEditUserForm, self).__init__()
        self.group_roles = FieldList(FormField(GroupRoleForm))
        for group in groups:
            self.group.label = group.name
            self.group.name = group.id
            self.group_roles.append_entry(self.group)  
            # If this doesn't create a copy of the GroupRoleForm 
            # superclass in group_roles, then you need a method to do it
            self.__clear_group()

    def __clear_group(self):
        # copy GroupRoleForm object, if needed
        # delete GroupRoleForm object
        ...
```

then you can call it like so:

```
form = forms.AdminEditUserForm(company.groups)
```