# Wtforms Forms, Syntax for acessing embedded Formfield

Tags: python, flask, wtforms

Trying to populate a `Wtform` form field, with data pulled out a mongo db database, then giving it to jinja/flask to create a editable pre-populated form for a REST system I'm building.

My form structure:

```
class ProjectForm(Form):
    name = TextField("Name of Project")     
    workflow =FieldList(TextField(""), min_entries=5)

class InstituteForm(Form):
    institue_name = TextField("Name of Institue")
    email = FieldList(TextField(""), min_entries=3)
    project_name = FormField(ProjectForm)
    submit = SubmitField("Send")`
```

I can pre-populate my field list using this syntax:

```
form = InstituteForm(institue_name="cambridge",
                     email=["email@gmail", "email@gmail"])
```

however, I cannot figure out the syntax for pre-populating a `FormField`, containing a form object.

First, I create a Project Form:

```
p = ProjectForm(name=" test", workflow=["adadadad", "adasdasd", "adasdadas"])
```

& now I am trying to add it to the `InstituteForm` form.

I have tried:

```
form = InstituteForm(institue_name=store_i,
                     project_name=p,
                     email=store_email)
```

for which I get html output:

Uploaded example output [http://tinypic.com/r/jpfz9l/5], do not have enough points to post an image to stack overflow.

and I have tried syntax like:

```
form = InstituteForm(institue_name=store_i,
                     project_name.name=p,
                     email=store_email)
```

and

```
form = InstituteForm(institue_name=store_i,
                     project_name=p.name,
                     email=store_email)
```

and even

```
form = InstituteForm(institue_name=store_i,
                     project_name=ProjectForm(name="this is a test"),
                     email=store_email)
```

Did search and found another thread (with no reply) to a similar question:

[Using FieldList and FormField](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12040688/using-fieldlist-and-formfield-with-wtforms)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are `project_name` [can be dict or object](https://bitbucket.org/simplecodes/wtforms/src/1b945d564d3907a3660f61e9c3f3928ff98e7a11/wtforms/fields/core.py?at=default#cl-705) (not form object because it will populate `InstituteForm.project_name` with html tag values), so you can use next code:

```
form = InstituteForm(institue_name="cambridge",
                     project_name=dict(name="test name"),
                     email=["email@gmail", "email@gmail"])
```

or

```
class Project(object):
    name = "test"
    workflow = ["test1", "test2"]

form = InstituteForm(institue_name="cambridge",
                     project_name=Project(),
                     email=["email@gmail", "email@gmail"])
```

or

```
class Project(object):
    name = "test"
    workflow = ["test1", "test2"]

class Institute(object):
    institue_name = "cambridge"
    project_name = Project()
    email = ["email@gmail", "email@gmail"]

form = InstituteForm(obj=Institute())
```

This examples equivalent because WTForms used constructor with `obj` parameters and `**kwargs` which work similar for this examples.