# Wtforms- Create Dict using formfield that has two values per key

Tags: python, dictionary, wtforms, flask-wtforms, formfield

I'd like to be able to collect both the track name and the start time for each track on a cd into a dict or json column in a table. 
I have defined a formfield to catch the data relating to the track names and save it in a dict:

```
class SeperateTracks(NoCsrfForm):
        track1 = TextField('track1')
        track2 = TextField('track2')
        track3 = TextField('track3')
        track4 = TextField('track4')

class SendForm(Form):
        alltracks = FormField(SeperateTracks)
```

This creates a dictionary that looks something like this so:

{"track1": "songname1", "track2": "songname2", "track3": "songname3", "track4": "songname4"}

What I'd like to achieve, is to have two TextFields per track- one for the track name and one for the start time of the track. 
I realize that in terms of creating more fields to accomodate this, I could simply create more text fields to hold the start time data like so:

```
class SeperateTracks(NoCsrfForm):
        track1 = TextField('track1')
        track2 = TextField('track2')
        track3 = TextField('track3')
        track4 = TextField('track4')
        starttime1 = TextField('starttime1')
        starttime2 = TextField('starttime2')
        starttime3 = TextField('starttime3') 
        starttime4 = TextField('starttime4')
```

However, this wouldn't associate the times with the corresponding tracks. What would be the recommended method for doing something like this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'd want something like this:

```
class Track(NoCsrfForm):
    songname = StringField('Song Name')
    starttime = StringField('start time')

class SeparateTracks(NoCsrfForm):
    tracks = FieldList(FormField(Track), min_entries=1, max_entries=4)
```

I made assumptions on `max_entries` based on your example, but it's not strictly required, and you can manage anywhere between 1 and N entries this way.

the data in python would look something like:

```
[{songname: "name 1", starttime: "123"}, {songname: "name 2", starttime: "456"}, ... ]
```

More info:

- See more on [Field Enclosures](http://wtforms.readthedocs.io/en/2.1/fields.html#field-enclosures) here.
- [A more extensive example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12040688/using-fieldlist-and-formfield)

Comment: Excellent thanks i'll give that a go and get back to you. One question- if I wanted to render, for example, a specific specific entry out of the max 4 entries, for example the  3rd one, how would I render it. I presume to render  the min_entries value it would be {{ form.tracks }} but what if I wanted to render a specific one?

Comment: You can render `{{ form.tracks.entries[2] }}` to get the 3rd entry (zero-indexed).  You can also iterate `form.tracks` to get all of the entries, and more.